# Is there any difference between 1U and 1 in C?

Tags: c, integer

```
    while ((1U << i) < nSize) {
        i++;
    }
```

Any particular reason to use `1U` instead of `1`?

Comment: This code is appearing in php's source code, in file [zend_hash.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/02457554a35fbb96fd3f51caf7deab91ca32ecb2/Zend/zend_hash.c#L154-L156).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On most compliers, both will give a result with the same representation.  However, according to the C specification, the result of a bit shift operation on a signed argument gives implementation-defined results, so in *theory* `1U << i` is more portable than `1 << i`.  In practice all C compilers you'll ever encounter treat signed left shifts the same as unsigned left shifts.

The other reason is that if `nSize` is unsigned, then comparing it against a signed `1 << i` will generate a compiler warning.  Changing the `1` to `1U` gets rid of the warning message, and you don't have to worry about what happens if `i` is 31 or 63.

The compiler warning is most likely the reason why `1U` appears in the code.  I suggest compiling C with most warnings turned on, and eliminating the warning messages by changing your code.

Comment: `1<<i` is not implementation-defined. It's well-defined as long as the value does not overflow `INT_MAX`, and *undefined behavior* if it does overflow (into the sign bit).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right (mostly).  It is undefined only if the result would not be representable in the result type (the standard doesn't mention sign bits, but since everyone uses twos-complement today, that's what happens).

Comment: To make the comments above very explicit, while `1U << 31` is fine, `1 << 31` is undefined behavior.

Comment: ... and `INT_MIN << 1;` is undefined, of course; it's not only `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 7):

1U is unsigned. It can carry values twice as big, but without negative values.

Depending on the environment, when using U, i can be a maximum of either 31 or 15, without causing an overflow. Without using U, i can be a maximum of 30 or 14.

31, 30 are for 32 bit int
15, 14 are for 16 bit int

Comment: no, they are not the same. 1U << 31 will work, 1 << 31 will cause an overflow.

Answer (score 4):

If nSize is an `int`, it can be maximum of 2147483647 (2^31-1).  If you use `1` instead of `1U` then `1 << 30` will get you 1073741824 and `1 << 31` will be -2147483648, and so the while loop will never end if nSize is larger than 1073741824.

With `1U << i`, `1U << 31` will evaluate to 2147483648, and so you can safely use it for nSize up to 2147483647.  If nSize is an unsigned int, it is also possible that the loop never ends, as in that case nSize can be larger than `1U << 31`.

**Edit:**  So I disagree with the answers telling you nSize should be unsigned, but if it is signed then it should not be negative...

Answer (score 1):

1U is unsigned.

The reason why they used an unsigned value in that is expression is (I guess) because `nSize` is unsigned too, and compilers (when invoked with certain parameters) give warnings when comparing a signed and an unsigned values.

Another reason (less likely, in my opinion, but we cannot know without knowing wath value `nSize` is supposed to assume) is that unsigned values can be twice as big as signed ones, so `nSize` could be up to ~4*10^9 instead of ~2*10^9.